# Which UI element is used in the android settings app?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-listview, android-settings

Here is a screenshot of my settings app running lollipop (Sony device):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVhvv.jpg
How might I go about adding a List using the UI elements the settings app uses? just the XML would be great.